# "cannot find stddef.h" error when compiling Ipopt example in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, standard-library, ipopt

I installed Ipopt debian package in ubuntu 16.04. When I tried to do an example problem given in the Ipopt documentation, I'm getting the following error

`/usr/include/coin/IpSmartPtr.hpp:18: error: #error "don't have header file for stddef"`

I hope some it is some dependency issue.
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can work around this by either doing

```
#define HAVE_CSTDDEF
#include <IpTNLP.hpp>
#undef HAVE_CSTDDEF
```

or

```
#define HAVE_STDDEF_H
#include <IpTNLP.hpp>
#undef HAVE_STDDEF_H
```

Try this [link](https://github.com/casadi/casadi/issues/1010).